# Which Tzemach Tzedek?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shulchan-aruch, issur-vheter

When the Pitchei Teshuva (on the daf of Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah) quotes teshuvot of the Tzemach Tzedek, who is he quoting? Is he quoting [Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneersohn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Schneersohn), the Tzemach Tzedek of Lubavitch or [Rabbi Menahem Mendel Krochmal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Krochmal), the Tzemach Tzedek of Nikolsburg?

Comment: The former died within 2 years of the author of Pitchei Teshuva. Data point.

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47325/5323

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [first print](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%97_%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%A7_%28%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%29) of the Tzemach Tzedek from Lubavitch was in 1871.

The [Pischei Teshuva](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%96%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%98) passed away in 1868.

Therefore it can be assumed that he never saw the Shu"t Tzemach Tzedek from Lubavitch.

[image: First print of the Shu"t Tzemach Tzedek]

Comment: Was that the first sefer to be published under that name by Lubavitchers?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt yes